# How to move to another UINavigationViewController using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How to i segue over to another UINavigationViewcController programmatically so there is a back button to go to the previous screen. I tried using this code, but it just models over.

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavViewController") as FirstMemberViewController

        self.presentViewController(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Try pushing the new UINavigationController onto the current UINavigationController's navigation stack, then the new navigation controller's first view controller

Comment: Do you want to present the new navigation controller or you want to push?

Comment: I want to show a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Your controllers
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
let viewController = UIViewController()

// The push
navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You should put `resultViewController`, if that is the controller you want to navigate to

Comment: Well you should replace the `navigationController` and the `viewController` with you own variable names.

Comment: Take a look over `UINavigationController` methods here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:

Comment: I tried using this code. it moved to the next view controller, but somethings wrong. It does not move to it properly...         navigationController?.showViewController(HomeViewController(), sender: UICollectionViewCell())

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

```
navigationController!.pushViewController(storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UIViewController, animated: true)
```